# Pythonic way of composing function calls with multiple arguments inside classes

Tags: python

According to this video (https://youtu.be/ka70COItN40?t=1185), it is not a good idea to store many intermediate variables with the same name in a program because the state of this variable would change during the execution of the program.

A better way, according to the author of the video, would be to use `reduce` from `functools` and define `compose()` function to chain the different data transformations.

To illustrate with an example, imagine that I'm writing a program to scrape some text from the web, and I need to clean it for analyzing it later. The "wrong" way to do it would be to implement it along the following lines:

```py
import regex
from html import unescape
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class MyAssignedClass():
    def __init__(self, description):
        self.description = description

    def clean_description(self):
        self.description = unescape(self.description)
        self.description = BeautifulSoup(self.description, "html.parser").text
        self.description = regex.sub("\n", " ", self.description)
        self.description = regex.sub("\xa0", ' ', self.description)
        self.description = regex.sub(" +", " ", self.description)

def main():
    text = "I'm full of <p> <tags> <li> <a> <whatever> \n \xa0 things to clean &amp to skip."
    
    A = MyAssignedClass(description=text)
    A.clean_description()
    print(f'MyAssignedClass.description: {A.description}')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output:

```
>>> MyAssignedClass.description: I'm full of things to clean & to skip.
```

If I follow the guidelines proposed in the video, I should create a `compose()` function instead to chain the transformations. The problem here is that I must use `lambda` functions everywhere to make it work:

```py
import regex
from html import unescape
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from typing import Callable
import functools

ComposableFunction = Callable[[str], str]

def compose(*functions: ComposableFunction) -> ComposableFunction:
    return functools.reduce(lambda f, g: lambda x: g(f(x)), functions)

class MyComposedClass():
    def __init__(self, description):
        self.description = description

    def clean_description(self):
        myfunc = compose(
            unescape, 
            lambda _: BeautifulSoup(_, features="html.parser").text,
            lambda _: regex.sub("\n", " ", _),
            lambda _: regex.sub("\xa0", ' ', _),
            lambda _: regex.sub(" +", " ", _)
            )

        self.description = myfunc(self.description)

def main():
    text = "I'm full of <p> <tags> <li> <a> <whatever> \n \xa0 things to clean &amp to skip."
    
    B = MyComposedClass(description=text)
    B.clean_description()
    print(f'MyComposedClass.description: {B.description}')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output:

```
>>> MyComposedClass.description: I'm full of things to clean & to skip.
```

However, wouldn't it be more readable to just use intermediate variables and assign `self.description` only at the end of the method?

```py
import regex
from html import unescape
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class MyUnderAssignedClass():
    def __init__(self, description):
        self.description = description

    def clean_description(self):
        _ = unescape(self.description)
        _ = BeautifulSoup(_, "html.parser").text
        _ = regex.sub("\n", " ", _)
        _ = regex.sub("\xa0", ' ', _)
        _ = regex.sub(" +", " ", _)
        self.description = _

def main():
    text = "I'm full of <p> <tags> <li> <a> <whatever> \n \xa0 things to clean &amp to skip."
    
    C = MyUnderAssignedClass(description=text)
    C.clean_description()
    print(f'MyUnderAssignedClass.description: {C.description}')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output:

```
>>> MyUnderAssignedClass.description: I'm full of things to clean & to skip.
```

Which are the most pythonic way of writing such piece of code? What are the pitfalls associated with using intermediate variables (and reasssigning the attribute many times within a method)?

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with the video author. This question is a great one but the suggestion from the video that `x = func(x)` should not be used is false in my opinion. For example in numpy it is completely fine to do these transformation with `x = func(x)` style. In the video example the `Compose` allows simplification of `forward` method and in a case where the network would be more complex (hundreds of layers) the original approach would be unpractical.

Let's see an example

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        # if these were all saved to class with `self.a = func1` or equivalent 
        # this would be unmaintainable
        self.functions = [generate_random_transform_function(x) for x in range(int(1e3))]
        # This combines the functions to be called all at once
        self.transform = compose(self.functions)
    def forward(self, x):
        # with list func
        # for f in self.functions:
        #    x = f(x)
        # return x
        # Or more horrible
        # x = self.x1(x)
        # x = self.x2(x)
        # <continues for a while>

        # compared to
        return self.transform(x)
```

This question is partly about functional versus object oriented approach to coding both of which are fine in python. Personally I prefer the more functional `x = f(x)` style.